# Attribute Routing - optional parameter not working?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#optionals-and-defaults

You can have optional parameters by adding a question mark (?) when using attribute routing. However it does not work for me (ASP.NET Web API 5).

```
    [Route("staff/{featureID?}")]
    public List<string> GetStaff(int? featureID) {
        List<string> staff = null;          
        return staff;
    }
```

If I use `staff/1` etc it works fine, if I use `/staff` I get the usual:

> "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI..."
>
> "No action was found on the controller  that matches
>   the request."

Am I missing a reference or something? Or doing it wrong?

Answer (score 9):

I also ran into the same issue and solved it a little differently. However, it still didn't work for me as laid out in that blog post. Instead of adding the default parameter value in the route definition I added it to the function definition.

I had to do this to for my example to work properly because I was using a `string` instead of an `int` and adding the default in the route definition of `null` caused my function parameter to have the string value `"null"`.

```
[Route("staff/{featureID?}")]
public List<string> GetStaff(int? featureID = null) {
    List<string> staff = null;          
    return staff;
}
```

Comment: Looking at that, it makes perfect sense as an optional argument on a normal method would be done that way, good insight on the "null" part as well

Answer (score 5):

This is because you always have to set a default value for an optional parameter, even if the default is null.  That is why this works:

```
[Route("staff/{featureID=null}")]
```

Comment: Then why have the '?' character functionality at all?

Comment: `[HttpGet][Route("GetFilterData/{job=null}")]public async Task<ActionResult<ReportFilterData>> GetFilterData(string job = null)` worked for me, it seems Microsoft broke the old pattern...

Answer (score 1):

If I do:

`[Route("staff/{featureID=null}")]`

instead of

`[Route("staff/{featureID?}")]`

It works.

Technically this doesn't answer my question but it gets me working!